# Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type when using mock with ts-jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have the following code and I am trying to run a Jest test using ts-jest.

```
jest.mock('../foo');
import configure from '../configure';
import foo from '../foo';

test('test name', () => {
  foo.mockImplementation(() => { methods: {}});   
  configure();
});
```

The function `configure` calls `foo` internally and I want to mock the `foo` function. However, when I run the test I get `Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type`.

I have checked the other answers on SO and I found out that there is a ts-jest helper called `mocked` which can be used to assert to TS that this is a mock ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924325/mock-forwardref-components-jest-mockimplementation-with-typescript)).

However, when I try to do `import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils'` as described there I get the error:

`Cannot find module 'ts-jest/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I looked at the docs for ts-jest but couldn't find anything. I found some docs for mocked on Github but they look like they are for older versions.

I also found [this](https://klzns.github.io/how-to-use-type-script-and-jest-mocks) that mentions that I can use `as jest.Mocked<typeof foo>;` but since I'm using ts-jest is that the best way?

Can someone please help me understand how to do this?

Comment: Cool that you found it out. It is completely valid to answer your own question and accept it. That makes it easier for future readers

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this I just found out that jest has a `mocked` utility (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions#comment124640523_58229293)) and apparently `ts-jest` has deprecated its own `mocked` in favor of that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions#comment124640523_58229293)).